# KendoUI Grid Dynamic Column's value update method

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I had a requiremenrt that make a grid with dynamic columns. I did with help of this [tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/forums/binding-kendoui-grid-to-dynamic-column-and-values-kendo-ui-complete-resources-buy-try) . So then I try to add update function to grid adding edit button .

Then I try to add update function....

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    transport : {
                        update: {

                        url: function (item) {

                            return "myURL" + item.id;
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "put"
                    }
                }
});
```

but when I edit data and press update button this did not trigger update function...
Can some one help me ??